# I need help how to create a responsive framework with divs inside other divs

Tags: html, css, templates, responsive-design, html5-canvas

Hello I am a beginner CSS and HTML enthusiast and I ran into a problem on how to make this sketch work for a responsive website. I have been trying for several days and I cant get it to work, it either works for me on mobile or desktop but not both. Can someone help me  how to approach this. Thanks

[This is how it should show on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92Vq.png)
[This is how it should show on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jTTY.png)

EDIT: Right now what I am trying to work on is how to align 6 div inside another parent div for the desktop version. This is what I have so far:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 3%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 5px;

}

.box2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  height: 90%;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 5px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box1">
      
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide code snippet, what you already tried.

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh oops , I thought I did! Thanks, I am editing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you want?
(Try out the below code in fullscreen)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background: #4472c4;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  transform: translateY(13%);
}

.wrapper {
  background: #ed7d31;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  width: 50vw;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.wrapper:nth-of-type(even) {
  width: 35vw;
}

.parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35vw;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.wrapper:nth-of-type(even) > .parent {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.wrapper > .parent > div {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #70ad47;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The notable thing here is the [`auto-fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) property of the grid layout which is responsible for automatic filing up the rows as the viewport size is shrinked.